# Connecting to MS SQL Server with iODBC on Mac

Tags: sql-server, macos, pyodbc, freetds, iodbc

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from my Mac development machine using iODBC. No matter what I do, I get the error message `Unable to connect to data source` from the FreeTDS driver. After consulting various manuals, blog posts, and StackOverflow questions, I'm at my wit's end.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.4, with FreeTDS version 0.91 installed through Homebrew. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ brew install freetds
$ mkvirtualenv odbc
$ workon odbc
$ pip install pyodbc

$ tsql -H localhost -U mydbusername -P mydbpassword -p 1433 
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> quit
```

The above connects and works, but:

```
$ iodbctest
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0607.1008

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): driver={TDS};server=localhost;uid=mydbusername;pwd=mydbpassword;database=mydbname
1: SQLDriverConnect = [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) SQLSTATE=08001
1: ODBC_Connect = [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) SQLSTATE=08001
```

Since I'm ultimately planning to use it through PyODBC, I tried that as well:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2012, 00:35:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> c = pyodbc.connect(driver='/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so', host='localhost', name='mydbname', uid='mydbusername', pwd='mydbpassword')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've tried all manner of things suggested in blog posts and SO posts... creating DSNs in ODBC Administrator, creating a `~/.odbc.ini`, attempting to use unixODBC (which didn't work with PyODBC), specifying a connection string instead of keyword args, etc. I also produced a trace file through iODBC, which I have pasted **[here](http://dpaste.org/DSbC6/)**, but I couldn't glean any more information from it than from the error message.

(I should mention that I am tunneling the connection to SQL Server over SSH with the line `LocalForward localhost:1433 production.someinstitution.edu:1433` in my `~/.ssh/config`, since my IT department has limited me to connect only from the production server's IP. It works for a GUI client (SQuirreLSQL) so I assume the forwarding is correct.)

Comment: Have you specified port in pyodbc connection string?

Comment: I **knew** it had to be something simple I was missing! Thank you so much sunprophit.

Noted for future reference: FreeTDS (or iODBC?) doesn't have a concept of 'default' port for a driver.

Comment: @sunprophit: Just checked, and it's working perfectly now! Can you post that as an answer so I can vote up / accept it?

Comment: What did you do to get iODBC to find the driver? Is there a config file you need to edit after you install FreeTDS via homebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 'port' parameter in connection string in case of DSN-less connection.

Otherwise your port could be specified in your DSN or driver config (odbc.ini and freetds.conf respectively)

Comment: Part of the reason it took so long to find this was that the exact code worked on my server with Ubuntu and unixODBC with FreeTDS. There, I could omit the port number and things would still work. (Hopefully if I have enough of the relevant keywords in this question and comments, nobody will have to waste time like I did!)